# Can InfluxDB have Continuous Queries with same source & target measurements but with different/new tags?

Tags: iot, influxdb, kapacitor

Below is the scenario against which I have this question.

**Requirement:**
Pre-aggregate time series data within influxDb with granularity of seconds, minutes, hours, days & weeks for each sensor in a device.

**Current Proposal:**
Create five Continuous Queries (one for each granularity level i.e. Seconds, minutes ...) for each sensor of a device in a different retention policy as that of the raw time series data, when the device is onboarded.

**Limitation with Current Proposal:**
With increased number of device/sensor (time series data source), the influx will get bloated with too many Continuous Queries (which is not recommended) and will take a toll on the influxDb instance itself.

**Question:**
To avoid the above problems, is there a possibility to create Continuous Queries on the same source measurement (i.e. raw timeseries measurement) but the aggregates can be differentiated within the measurement using new tags introduced to differentiate the results from Continuous Queries from that of the raw time series data in the measurement.

**Example:**

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "strain_seconds" ON "database"
RESAMPLE EVERY 5s FOR 1m
BEGIN
  SELECT MEAN("strain_top") AS "STRAIN_TOP_MEAN" INTO "database"."raw"."strain" FROM "database"."raw"."strain" GROUP BY time(1s),*
END
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, and have seen from the docs, it's not possible to apply new tags in continuous queries.

If I've understood the requirements correctly this is one way you could approach it.

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "strain_seconds" ON "database"
RESAMPLE EVERY 5s FOR 1m
BEGIN
  SELECT MEAN("strain_top") AS "STRAIN_TOP_MEAN" INTO "database"."raw"."strain" FROM "database"."strain_seconds_retention_policy"."strain" GROUP BY time(1s),*
END
```

This would save the data in the same measurement but a different retention policy - `strain_seconds_retention_policy`. When you do a `select` you specify the corresponding retention policy from which to select.
Note that, it is not possible to perform a `select` from several retention policies at the same time. If you don't specify one, the default one is used (and not all of them). If it is something you need then another approach could be used.

I don't quite get why you'd need to define a continuous query per device and per sensor. You only need to define five (1 per seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks) and do a `group by *` (all) which you already do. As long as the source datapoint has a tag with the id for the corresponding device and sensor, the resampled datapoint will have it too. Any newly added devices (data) will just be processed automatically by those 5 queries and saved into the corresponding retention policies.

If you do want to apply additional tags, you could process the data outside the database in a custom script and write it back with any additional tags you need, instead of using continuous queries

Comment: The reason I am defining CQ per device per sensor is due to the equipment modelling as well as the storage model confirmed by architects. I agree, even I would have preferred storage model per device.

W.r.t. new tags, I was planning to differentiate computed aggregates with aggregation levels so that I can use one measurement to store all aggregation granularity differentiated by these additional tags on this measurement.

In such use case, what is your opinion on Kapacitor implementation? Would it be a better approach?

Comment: Indeed with Kapacitor you could probably do what you need or you could implement it in code in an external service. The aggregation levels, I'm guessing, are a performance optimization? You'd do usually do this in retention policies that automatically remove data after some period of time. High granularity data becomes less relevant with time. And if you are trying to keep things fast then you should be discarding as much of the data as you can (from short term storage, obviously you'd archive it somewhere else)